# How to kill all RDP sessions using powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell

I am writing powershell script like below but unable to read a sessionids from the query result then kill all the active sessions.

```
$queryResults = quser /server:$server; Write-Output "users : $users";
        foreach($queryResult in $queryResults){                    
          Write-Output "session ID : $queryResult.sessionid";  
         }
```

Any suggestion how to read a session ids from the queryResult then logoff all the sessions.

Comment: Just loop through and logoff all the session IDs: `logoff $SessionId`

Comment: I guess $SessionId is just a variable but my Qs is how to read a session ids then store to $SessionId

Comment: Quser doesn't output objects just text; it's not a powershell command.  You've been spoiled by powershell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the output of quser (it's not a PS command so the output is a simple string) - I've done it this way so that you receive an object that's more useful:

```
$server = 'myserver'

# Get list of logged in users
$queryResults = quser /server:$server

# Parse the quser output and store results in a new object. Skip first line as that's just headers.
$UserList = $queryResults | Select-Object -Skip 1 -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object {

  # Split up the current line into its elements
    $CurrentLine = $_.Trim() -Replace '\s+',' ' -Split '\s'

  # Create a new object from all the line elements. If session is disconnected different fields will be selected
    If ($CurrentLine[2] -eq 'Disc') {
        $SearchResult = [pscustomobject]@{
            UserName = $CurrentLine[0];
            SessionName = $null;
            Id = $CurrentLine[1];
            State = $CurrentLine[2];
            IdleTime = $CurrentLine[3];
            LogonTime = $CurrentLine[4..($CurrentLine.GetUpperBound(0))] -join ' '
        }
     }
     Else {
        $SearchResult = [pscustomobject]@{
            UserName = $CurrentLine[0];
            SessionName =  $CurrentLine[1];
            Id = $CurrentLine[2];
            State = $CurrentLine[3];
            IdleTime = $CurrentLine[4];
            LogonTime = $CurrentLine[5..($CurrentLine.GetUpperBound(0))] -join ' '
        }
     }
  # Output the custom object (stores it in $UserList)
     $SearchResult
}

# Display a list of users/states/Id
$UserList | Select-Object UserName, Id, State, IdleTime

# To logoff everyone, you can just loop through

#$UserList | ForEach-Object {
#    logoff $_.Id
#}

# Or you could just logoff the disconnected users:


#$UserList | Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Disc'} | ForEach-Object {
#    logoff $_.Id
#}
```

Comment: thanks for you reply. please can tell what is happening at this point [pscustomobject]@

Comment: It creates a custom object with the names and values specified. e.g. UserName is given the value of the element at position 0 in the `$CurrentLine` variable

Comment: To anyone trying out this script, watch out, it logs everyone off.

Comment: That was the requirement.... but yes, take your point, I'll comment them out