# How to LOGOFF users and if there is no users then how I stop showing errors using powershell

Tags: powershell

Actually when I try logoff users it work when there's users, But it showing errors when there's no users.

I want a script that logoff users but doesn't show any errors if there's no users.

So I tried this script

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
try
{
((quser.exe).Trim(' ','>') -replace '\s{20,39}',',,') -replace '\s{2,}',',' | ConvertFrom-Csv |
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        if ($_.UserName -notmatch "$env:USERNAME")
        {
          
            if ($_.ID -ne $null)
            {
              $_.Id





          }
            else
            {
             break
            }
    
        }
      }
  }
  catch
  {
  if(($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) -or ($_.Exception.Message -match 'No User exists for *')) {
    $LASTEXITCODE = 0
     break
  }
  }
```

Comment: `quser 2>$null`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74302307/how-to-kill-all-rdp-sessions-using-powershell-script/74302510#74302510

Answer (score 0):

2>$null hides the standard error output of external programs, assuming you're referring to quser output.

```
quser 2>$null
```